# How to increment all numbers in selected text?

Tags: text-editors, find-and-replace

How to increment all numbers in selected text?
For example:

turn this text:

```
hello1
hello2
```

to this:

```
hello2
hello3
```

Windows 10. Any software with this functionality would be fine.

Comment: which editor? which platform? Usually you have to use a scripting tool for this purpose

Comment: Actually trying to do this in Android studio, Windows 10, but I don't expect Android studio to have this function. Any editor would be fine. Maybe Notepad++ or something else. Maybe finding good editor would be more efficient than writting script for myself.

Comment: How many lines are present in the text? Edit your question and add real lines (more than 2) and expected result. I guess `hello1`, `hello2` are not literally what you want to modify.

Comment: @Toto I want it to work with as many lines and digits as I want. If there is count "22", it should become "23". "Edit your question and add real lines" - they are my "real" lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex doesn't calculate.

---

Using Notepad++, you can install Python script plugin (*via* menu Plugins > Plugin Admin ...)

When installed, create a script like:

```
import re

def calculate(match):
    return '%s' % (str(int(match.group(1)) + 1))

editor.rereplace('(\d+)$', calculate)
```

and save it as `calculate.py` (for example).

Open the file you want to modify, then choose in menu Plugins > Python script > Script > calculate

→ Done. All the numbers in the file are incremented by 1.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful.